# Choosing best database for billions of reads/writes per day - Cassandra is as slow as a snail

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I'm comparing different databases for one of our projects.
We need 1 billion inserts/day and billions of reads (each select statement should read 50 rows).

Each record has few fields, mostly id columns and a 500 bytes blob in average.

I'm trying to simulate in my machine.
I can reach 50,000 inserts/second in file system (which is not good as it wastes a lot of space per record).

I can reach 30,000 inserts/second in mongodb (but I read that it's not good in replication/partitioned nodes).

I can reach 20,000 inserts/second in mysql, meh.

But Cassandra, too slow to consider: barely 1,500 inserts per second!
At first I believed the problem is with the driver I'm using, then I tried different drivers, not so different. I tried to insert by multiple processes, but still much slower than others.

All benchmarks are saying that Cassandra is fastest, but I get poor results. What am I missing?

A normal Schema we need is like bellow (*_uid is 20 byte binary data and is guaranteed to be in ascending order & unique):

```
create table records
              (
              record_uid blob PRIMARY KEY,
              user_uid blob,
              product_uid blob,
              data blob
              );
```

Also, is there any better suggestion that fits our needs with less costs?

p.s. Here is the code I used to test:

```
$cluster  = Cassandra::cluster()->build();
$keyspace  = 'benchmark';
$session  = $cluster->connect($keyspace);

$prepare    = $session->prepare("INSERT INTO records (record_uid, user_uid, product_uid, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");




$start = microtime(true);


for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    $values = [
        'message_uid' => new Cassandra\Blob(uuid()),
        'user_uid' => new Cassandra\Blob(uuid()),
        'room_uid' => new Cassandra\Blob(uuid()),
        'message' => new Cassandra\Blob('This is a test!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    ];


    $options = ['arguments' => $values];
    $session->execute($prepare, $options);
}


$time = microtime(true) - $start;
$insert_per_second = $time / $i;

echo "execution time: $time seconds\r\n"; // ~100 seconds
echo "insert per second: $insert_per_seconds\r\n"; // ~1500 records / sec
```

Comment: Do not push all that traffic on one server. You need distributed persistence.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, sure, but 1,000 inserts per second is too slow. That means we need a lot of nodes to handle the request, compared to other solutions like mongodb.

Comment: I have had cassandra deployment with 1M writes/sec with less than 10ms insert latency. Cassandra is for best for high inserts than reads not for reverse but it take very good read load as well. Key is distribution of keys and other performance tuning. Billion writes/sec is beyond limits for any database. it too to huge to handle unless you are at google's scale. Make sure you need such load.

Comment: @NachiketKate, how did you reached 1 million insert/sec? on one instance? 50 nodes? Do you have any code samples or configuration file (cassandra.yaml)? By my tests, I need at least 1,000 nodes to reach 1m writes/sec. Also our need is 1 billion/day, not per second. Peak inserts is 500k/sec.

Comment: 1k/sec is very slow for cassandra, a basic default setup should easily do 20k/sec, a good server should push 200k writes/sec. billions of writes a sec your likely gonna need to be scaled out to 1000 nodes **just** for storage or you will run out of disk, unless your just overriding a small set of data - in which case you should look at a different in memory db thats faster like redis, aerospike, or something more focused on speed than HA.

Comment: include a link to your benchmark in github or something if you can, likely issue is with your test.

Comment: Do you use async API for insertion of data? prepared queries?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I updated the question details with sample code.

Comment: @AlexOtt I used prepared statements. I updated the question details with sample code.

Comment: @AlexOtt this code is written in prepared statements by using DataStax driver. I tried async API on other drivers, but they were not much different too. I was compiled cassandra from source, and deleted it and just reinstalled Cassandra by pouring from brew, but nothing changed.

Comment: You're using sync API - use async API for tests, and tune the number of in-flight-requests...

Comment: @AlexOtt Thank you Alex! I just switched to Async API of DataStax driver, I reached 11k insert per second. 10x better than before. It seems that DataStax driver is much better in async mode comparing to others that I tested before. But it's still much slower than databases, specially mongodb.

Comment: @AlexOtt Could you please tell me how can I find in-flight-requests option? I clouldn't find it in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: No, it's not in the `cassandra.yaml`, but in the connection's configuration. I don't know how to do this in PHP, but I believe that concept is similar to the Java's: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/pooling/ Also, it was mentioned in the comments above, you need to test multi-machine setup, as driver is smart enough to send data to the node(s) that own the corresponding data range.

Comment: @S.D I had 6 node c4.4x/r3.4x instance cluster. You can run sample benchmarks on Mongo, Cassandra , Aerospike, Redis etc. using YCSB frameworks. Again don't consider only read-write throughput for db selection but also consider data access patterns (query distribution), future growth, maintainance, HA/DR etc to make final selection.

Comment: OK. I am so BIASED, but have you considered ArangDB yet?
https://www.arangodb.com/performance/